# UltiSnips not substituting text properly

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex

I am trying to define a snippet which substitutes text in multiple places. As a trivial example see the following which works for me :

```
snippet abc "Testing" bmA
\begin{${1:text_here}}
 $0
\end{${1:text_here}}
```

Now, when this snippet is expanded whatever I substitute for `text_here` in the first instance gets automatically substituted in the second instance as well. I want to expand this to write the preamble of my code as follows  :

```
snippet notes "creates a template to take notes" bm

% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[${1:12pt}]{${2:article}}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}

${3:%}\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
${3:%}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
${3:%}\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={6,10}]

${4:%}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
${4:%}\usepackage{garamondx}
${4:%}\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
${4:%}\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{${5:Title}}
\author{${6:Author}}
${7:%}\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
 \maketitle
\end{tcolorbox}
%\par\noindent\rule[0.5cm]{\textwidth}{1pt}

${0:start_hammering}

\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}



\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
endsnippet
```

This fails to work. What I want to do is achieve similar result as that of the simple example I showed above. When my cursor reaches `$3` and I start typing : it is only substituted in one instance of `$3` and not all the instances. Likewise for `$4` as well. To be crystal clear, my goal here is to do the following : if I delete the default text (`%`) appearing at the first instance of `$3` and all the instances of `$3` should be modified accordingly.

Can someone please help me figure out how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only set a default value on the first occurrence of the placeholder, that way it works.

From [`:help UltiSnips-mirrors`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/e83c82099d9bd43dc7895e3cb5b114ee5a2a07c6/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L1161):

> [...] A mirrored tabstop can have a default value defined. **Only the first instance of the tabstop need have a default value.** Mirrored tabstop will take on the default value automatically.

While the help says *"need"*, it only works for me (including on your `abc` example snippet) when the mirrors have no default value.

So where you currently have this:

```
${3:%}\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
${3:%}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
${3:%}\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={6,10}]

${4:%}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
${4:%}\usepackage{garamondx}
${4:%}\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
${4:%}\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
```

Use this instead:

```
${3:%}\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
$3\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
$3\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={6,10}]

${4:%}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
$4\usepackage{garamondx}
$4\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
$4\usepackage{bm} %for boldface math
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
```

Comment: Working for me when only the first mirror has a default value and rest have no value. Thank you. Should have read the documentation :(

Comment: @Nitin To be fair, my re-reading of the docs imply that it *should* work when more than one has the default, it only says they don't *need* to have the default... Perhaps the docs could be improved here a little bit... Glad this fixed it for you though!